# Площадь фигуры, построенной в Shape

Tags: delphi

Как определить площадь фигуры построенную в Shape (Delphi 7)? Только уточняю, нужна не площадь компоненты, а площадь фигуры, которую рисует данный компонент. Не имею представления, где взять данные для формулы по вычислению площади... Если таковые вообще имеются...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если свойство компонента Shape Shape1 не равно stRoundRect или stRoundSquare - тут всё просто:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  S: Extended;
begin
  S:=0;
  If (Shape1.Shape = stRectangle) Then S:=Shape1.Width*Shape1.Height
  Else If (Shape1.Shape = stEllipse) Then S:=Shape1.Width*Shape1.Height*Pi/4
  Else If (Shape1.Shape = stSquare) Then
    If (Shape1.Width>Shape1.Height) Then
      S:=Sqr(Shape1.Height)
    Else S:=Sqr(Shape1.Width)
  Else If (Shape1.Shape = stCircle) Then
    If (Shape1.Width>Shape1.Height) Then
      S:=Pi*Sqr(Shape1.Height/2)
    Else S:=Pi*Sqr(Shape1.Width/2)
  Else ShowMessage('Это выше моих вычислительных способностей!');
  If (S=0) Then Exit
  Else ShowMessage('S = '+IntToStr(Round(S)));
end;
```

Сложность вычисления в случаях, когда свойство компонента Shape Shape1 равно stRoundRect или stRoundSquare заключается в том, что необходимо получить площадь астроиды (эта не захваченная фигурой область, образующаяся в результате скругления, её площадь -  S=3*Pi*R/8). Главное её найти площадь, чтобы её вычесть из площади квадрата или прямоугольника, а её площадь найти я пока не знаю как, поскольку радиус скругления зависит от размеров самого компонента Shape.

Comment: Спасибо все верно)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант
заливать всю фигуру одним цветом , а потом считать сколько закрашенных пикселей